# Why does every anyon need to have an antiparticle?

Tags: antimatter, anyons

It seems to be a basic requisite to every anyonic model that every type of anyon, say $a$ in the theory comes with an antiparticle $\bar{a}$ (which can be itself) where $a$ and $\bar{a}$ fuse together to the vacuum, i.e. have trivial statistics when viewed as a composite.

Why is the existence of an antiparticle a necessity for a sound anyonic theory?

Comment: One thing to consider is that the anyon has to live in a fundamentally 3+1 dimensional world that only has fermions and bosons. So all anyons should be able to be reassembled to make a their fundamental fermion/bosons. Since an anyon is essentially "half" a fermion, then you'll need at least two of them

Comment: @KFGauss I have to admit I didn't follow that at all -- could you expand that into an answer?

Comment: @KFGauss I dont think "an anyon is essentially half a fermion" applies to a generic anyon theory. It applies of course to Majorana fermions but I am interested in generic anyon theories.

Answer (score 5):

A anyon without anti-particle would be an allowed excitation on the plane, but not on the sphere (because all the excitations on a sphere have to fuse to the vacuum). So as long as you demand that the possible *local* excitations don't depend on the *global* topology, it must be the case that particles have anti-particles.

An example of a system where the allowed local excitations don't depend on the global topology is a Hamiltonian built of commuting local projectors. So at least any topological phase that can be realized by commuting projectors must have anti-particles.

More generally, (but less rigorously) you can try to argue from the point of view that a topological quantum field theory should be invariant under Euclidean rotations in space-time. So if you can have a world-line of particle $a$ pointing in the $+t$ direction, then you can also have a world-line pointing of $a$ pointing in the $-t$ direction, which is equivalent to a world-line of $\overline{a}$ in the $+t$ direction.

I think it's an interesting question, though, whether in non-relativistic systems you could get topological phases which are topological in terms of the spatial degrees of freedom, but don't necessarily allow for space and time to get rotated into each other. I believe some people would call these "H-type" theories (instead of "L-type") because they would be defined in terms of a topological Hamiltonian rather than a topological action/Lagrangian.

Comment: I think I'm missing the crucial step: why should "all the excitations on a sphere have to fuse to the vacuum"? This is presumably not true for non-anyons, because otherwise it would show that all field theories (including nonrelativistic ones) have antiparticles. Is the key idea here something like, you can pump in some energy and other conserved quantities into a general field theory from outside to make excitations, but you can't pump in "topological charge"?

Comment: @knzhou The statement about the sphere is to the extent that you mod out by "transparent" particles -- those which cannot be detected by braiding something else around them. On the sphere, if you draw a loop around all the excitations, then it can always be shrunk to a point (without touching the excitations), so the combination of all the excitations must be transparent. The non-topological particles in some non-relativistic field theory certainly are transparent, so they would be identified with the vacuum for our purposes here.

Comment: Aha, right, of course!

Comment: I have to say I cannot really follow your argument either and your comment about "transparent" particles does not help me much. Do you have any references in mind that could help me grasp this?